# Domain and range of an inverse trigonometric composite function.

Tags: functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

arcsin([x]/{x}) - what will the domain and range of such a function be?Here, [x] implies the greatest integer function while {x} is the fractional part function.

I tried using the fact that for arcsin(к), к has to be between [-1,1]. This yielded no concrete results. Is the only way to check values here?

Comment: You need to solve the inequality $-1\le [x]/\left\{x\right\}\le 1$ Note that $\left\{x\right\}=0$ if and only if $x$ is an integer and that $\left\{x\right\}=x-[x]$. So, if $k-[x]$, you have to solve $-1\le \frac{k}{x-k}\le 1$ with $k<x<k+1$.